# couple of questions in probability

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm trying to solve some questions and I'm not sure if I'm solving it correctly.

**Question 1:**
" A boy participating in a game and throwing normal dice,
if the dice shows the number 6 the game is over.
Else, the boy need to wait the number of minutes the dice shows. For example: if the dice shows 4 the boy need to wait 4 minutes and then continue playing. What is the Expected value the boy will wait?

**My answer:**
$x$ is a random variable that gets the values ($1, \ldots, 6$) with the same probability, so the expected value should be $$2.5 = \frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5) + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 0$$

**Question 2:**
The number of earthquakes in a year at  a country is  a Poisson variable with $2 = \lambda$.  Given that in certain year the the number of earthquakes was $2$, what is the probability that the $2$ earthquakes accord at the first $3$ months of the year?

**My answer:**
I am not sure that my way is correct it thought that I divide $\lambda$  by $4$,then $\lambda$ is the number of earthquakes in a $1/4$ of a year
and then I get that the answer is $0.0758$, but I am not sure this is the right way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I am not good at probability. At all. But here you are assuming that after the first throw you’re gonna have a success

Comment: yes it s a normal dice i fixed it

Comment: Dave, it looks like you have to continue playing the game if you don't get a $6$. So you have to take that into account, and not just one roll.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон so i nedd to say  xi =5k/6 + 0*1/6 for k =(1,2,3,4,5) ?

Comment: @Dave Check the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1)

Let $X$ denote the waiting time and let $D$ denote the result of the first throw.

Then:

$$X\stackrel{d}{=}\left(D+Y\right)\mathsf{1}_{D\neq6}$$ where $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$
and $Y$ and $D$ are independent.

This based on the observation that the time takes value $0$ if the first throw results in a $6$ and the process starts over otherwise in the understanding that $D$ waiting minutes are gained.

Taking expectation on both sides we find:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}D\mathsf{1}_{D\neq6}+\mathbb{E}Y\mathbb{E}\mathsf{1}_{D\neq6}=\frac{5}{2}+\mathbb{E}X\cdot\frac{5}{6}$$
leading to: $$\mathbb{E}X=15$$

---

Hint on Q2):

If $X$ denotes the number of earthquakes in a year then we can write:
$$X=Y+Z$$ where $Y$ denotes the number of earthquakes in the first
3 months of that year and $Z$ denotes the number of earthquakes in
the other months of that year.

Then $Y$ and $Z$ are independent with $Y\sim\mathsf{Poisson}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$
and $Z\sim\mathsf{Poisson}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$ .

To be found is $P\left(Y=2\mid X=2\right)$.

Comment: Thank you!! i have one question, what is it E1?

Comment: If $A$ denotes an event then $1_A:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ denotes the random variable that takes value $1$ if $\omega\in A$ (in words: if event $A$ occurs) and takes value $0$ otherwise. This random variable has an expectation $\mathbb E1_A=P(A)$. In my anwer we are dealing with $A=\{D\neq6\}$. I abbreviate $1_{\{D\neq6\}}$ as $1_{D\neq6}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for Question 2**

If we know that $n$ events with a Poisson distribution have occurred in a time interval $[0, t]$, then their arrival times have the same distribution as $n$ independent random variables having a Uniform($0,t$) distribution.

(Reference: *Introduction to Probability Models, 9th Edition* by Sheldon M. Ross, Theorem 5.2)